# Calculating time period for equivalent simple interest and discount rate

Tags: linear-algebra

If a simple interest rate of 24% per year, is equivalent to a simple disount rate of 20,5% per year,
then the time under consideration is approximately?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It looks like it is not a full period.  I would think 1 full period the discount rate and interest rate would be equal.  Since this not the case I’d solve for x to find number of days for n.  $.24x =.205$If equation is solved for x.  $x=.8541$. Then there are 365 days in the year.  Multiple 365 by .8541.  And n = approximately 311.8 days.

Comment: can you please share the detailed calculation?.